# Length of wire required for a coil length of $x$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I was doing a recent project and was making a coil around a pipe and I was trying to find the length of wire required to make a coil of length $x$ cm. The wire has a thickness of 1cm and the pipe has an outer diametre of 3cm. I wanted to coil the wire around the pipe with no gaps between the coils so that they are all touching. This was my calculation, $$\pi\cdot\left(3+1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{x}{1}\right)=\operatorname{Length of wire}.$$
I believe this is flawed but can't figure out a better method.

Comment: "Unroll" the coil onto a (flat) plane, and the math becomes trivial.

Comment: I think adding wire thickness to diameter is too generous. Otherwise, your method is OK.

Comment: I have tried both ways and it never seems to turn out right with the calculation it is always less than the amount I actually used

Comment: Is your wire really $1$ centimeter thick? I would call it a rod, rather than a wire... How can you bend it around a $3$ cm tube???